# How to add host configuration to an existing Api Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I am trying to add new host configuration to the existing deployed Api management using arm with bicep code.

```
var CUSTOMDOMAIN_CONFIG = {
  type: customDomainType
  hostName: customDomainHostName
  keyVaultId: 'https://${existing_keyvault.name}.vault.azure.net/secrets/${customDomainKVCert}'
}

var HOST_CONFIG = bool(customDomainConfig) ? CUSTOMDOMAIN_CONFIG : {}

resource apiManagementService 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-08-01' = {
  name: replace(resourceGroup().name, '-rg', '-apim')
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  sku: {
    name: sku
    capacity: skuCount
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: publisherEmail
    publisherName: publisherName
    hostnameConfigurations: [
      HOST_CONFIG
    ]
  }
}
```

This always replace the existing host configuration instead of adding new one.
I see that we cannot use properties on existing resources.

tried to use below approach also to add on existing apim, not successded.

```
 resource apimGateway 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/gateways@2022-08-01' = {
   name: 'string'
   parent: apiManagementService
 }

 resource apimHostNameConfig 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/gateways/hostnameConfigurations@2022-08-01' = {
   name: '${apiManagementService.name}-apiHostNameConfig'
   parent: apimGateway
   properties: {
     certificateId: 'string'
     hostname: apiGatewayHostname
   }
}
```

These properties are different than above.
Can you please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: Try the code from this MS document here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/gateways/hostnameconfigurations?pivots=deployment-language-bicep and check if it works?

Comment: If you see the 2nd piece of code. Thats the same. However properties are different and that is specific for gateway. Not for Developer Portal. Not sure how it works.

Comment: Try  name: '${apimGateway.name}/myNewHostNameConfig' with / instead of - and rerun your code any luck?

Comment: Regarding that document you need to create API first with this Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/gateways/hostnameconfigurations?pivots=deployment-language-bicep and then certificates https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/gateways/certificateauthorities?pivots=deployment-language-bicep and then hostnameconfigurations - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/gateways/hostnameconfigurations?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: yeah gateway is different form what you are looking at.

Comment: `hostnameConfigurations` is not a sub resource so you can't achieve that easily

Comment: I am trying to do the same because I want to first create the APIM with system assigned managed identity, then setup my keyvault permissions, then setup the hostname configs to reference keyvault. If I don't do it in this order then apim is not able to access keyvault and fails.